# javascript/jQuery, asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Problem: how to wait with further code execution until the function returns some value?

Simple explanation:
I have an ajax request that returns some data, say animal groups: [Mammals, Birds, Reptiles], then in a loop I pass each of them as an argument to another function that do ajax request and returns for first element [Dog, Cat, Horse]... and then again ajax with [Dog] parameter that returns [Husky, Terrier, etc.].

The pseudocode looks something like:

```
function ask_breed(species){
    var breed = $.getJSON('web');
    var res;
    breed.done(function (data)  {
        for (z in data){
            res += z;
        }
    }
}
function ask_species(group){
    var species = $.getJSON('web');
    var res;
    species.done(function (data) {
        for (z in data){
            res += z;
            res += ask_breed(z);
        }
    }
}
function ask_group(){
    var groups = $.getJSON('web');
    var res;
    groups.done(function (data) {
        for (z in data){
            res += z;
            res += ask_species(z);
        }
    }
}
ask_group();
```

When it's failing: 
When I update the result string, I'm getting 'undefined' instead of real data. The function is called correctly, but the result arrives with delay (tried with console.log).

I was trying to deal with it with 'done', and $.Deffered, and promises, but I just cannot make it work, it's not clear even after reading good dozen of articles about it.

Or maybe simpler version of problem:

```
function second_stage(param){
    level2 = setTimeout(function(){console.log(param); return param;}, 3000);
    return level2;
}
function initial(){
    second_stage(1);
}
initial();
```

Comment: Are you looking for [JavaScript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

Comment: Alternatively, since you're using [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) can't you just move a bunch of these into the [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) callback?

Comment: You order a pizza and as soon as you submit it you try to eat it! It does not happen because the delivery process is asynchronous. You can not return!

Comment: You can define a variable and set that variable in AJAX success or .done() method.But if you expect a return from a function based on AJAX response then u should do async :false AJAX request.If u still need aync call. The call the corresponding functions in .done() method of each.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take advantage of the new syntax sugar around Promises - [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keywords.

Here is an example from the documentation

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function method1(){
  //AJAX call
  .done(function(data){
    method2(data);
  });
}

function method2(data2){
  //AJAX call
  .done(function(data2){
    method3(data2);
  });
}
```

Calling each method on success of each AJAX will do.